# MVC 5 - how to add id into anchor tag

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5

So my view looks like -

```
@model IEnumerable<PlacingTechiesV3.Models.Category>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>
        <a href="~/Views/Jobs">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)</a>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Within my Category model, I have a field called CategoryId. How do I add that to the href of the anchor tag, so it looks like "~/Views/Jobs/[id]", where [id] is the CategoryId?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, then you could try: `<a href="~/Views/Jobs" id="yourIdHere">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You can just add @item.CategoryId to the href assuming it's part of the item, if it's part of the main model, then it would be @Model.CategoryId

```
@model IEnumerable<PlacingTechiesV3.Models.Category>
<ul>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>
        <a href="~/Views/Jobs/@item.CategoryId">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryName)</a>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ActionLink` instead. It will generate an anchor for you.

```
@Html.ActionLink(item.CategoryName, "Jobs", "Views", new { id = item.CategoryId })
```